# Select row N based on values from row N-1 across list of data frames

Tags: r, list

I've searched through previous answered questions and haven't been able to construct a functioning solution yet. Here's my situation with demo data:

Say I have subjects complete a computer task where they give a response on each trial. I end up with data from each trial regarding whether they gave the accurate response and what their reaction time was:

```
sub1 <- data.frame(acc = round(rnorm(10, mean=.65, sd=.25), 0), RT = round(rnorm(10, mean=270, sd=30), 0))
sub2 <- data.frame(acc = round(rnorm(10, mean=.65, sd=.25), 0), RT = round(rnorm(10, mean=270, sd=30), 0))
sub3 <- data.frame(acc = round(rnorm(10, mean=.65, sd=.25), 0), RT = round(rnorm(10, mean=270, sd=30), 0))

sub.list <- list(sub1, sub2, sub3)
```

I've created a list where each element is a subject's data.

```
> sub.list
[[1]]
   acc  RT
1    1 259
2    0 187
3    1 256
4    1 288
5    1 304
6    1 265
7    1 312
8    1 196
9    1 335
10   0 276

[[2]]
   acc  RT
1    1 215
2    0 325
3    1 290
4    0 297
5    0 281
6    1 294
7    0 289
8    1 252
9    0 364
10   0 241

[[3]]
   acc  RT
1    0 292
2    0 267
3    0 240
4    1 321
5    1 292
6    0 269
7    1 241
8    1 206
9    1 250
10   1 283
```

Now comes my issue. I want to create another column for each subject that only has the RTs for accurate trials that were also preceded by an accurate response. Here's a **non**-working for-loop and an example of what I'm trying to end up with.

```
for(i in 1:length(sub.list)){
  for(j in 2:nrow(sub.list[[i]])){
    if(sub.list[[i]][(j-1), "acc"]==1 & sub.list[[i]][j, "acc"]==1){
      sub.list[[i]][j,]$correct.RT <- sub.list[[i]][j, "RT"]
    } else {
      sub.list[[i]][j,]$correct.RT <- NA
    }
  }
}

> sub.list
[[1]]
   acc  RT correctRT
1    1 259        NA
2    0 187        NA
3    1 256        NA
4    1 288       288
5    1 304       304
6    1 265       265
7    1 312       312
8    1 196       196
9    1 335       335
10   0 276        NA

[[2]]
   acc  RT correctRT
1    1 215        NA
2    0 325        NA
3    1 290        NA
4    0 297        NA
5    0 281        NA
6    1 294        NA
7    0 289        NA
8    1 252        NA
9    0 364        NA
10   0 241        NA

[[3]]
   acc  RT correctRT
1    0 292        NA
2    0 267        NA
3    0 240        NA
4    1 321        NA
5    1 292       292
6    0 269        NA
7    1 241        NA
8    1 206       206
9    1 250       250
10   1 283       283
```

My reason for doing this is so that I can perform functions on these trials alone. For example:

```
> sapply(sub.list, function(x) mean(x$correctRT, na.rm=TRUE))
[1] 283.3333      NaN 257.7500
```

I know there must be a way to accomplish this with mapply or one of the other apply functions rather than a clumsy, slow for loop, but my hang up is how to reference sequential rows.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Not quite, correctRT should be NA when sub.list[N, "acc"] == 0 **OR** sub.list[(N-1), "acc"] == 0. Hope that's more clear. I want RTs from trials with acc = 1 that do not come after an error has been made (acc = 0 on the immediately above row).

Comment: To make your data reproducible, please start with something like `set.seed(123)` if you are going to use random samples.

Comment: Oops sorry. Not too familiar with generating random samples in R but that's very useful to know. I will do this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sub.list <- lapply(sub.list, transform,
                   correctRT = ifelse(acc & c(0, head(acc, -1)), RT, NA))
```

But given your final goal, I would rather create a flag (TRUE/FALSE) variable:

```
sub.list <- lapply(sub.list, transform,
                   is.valid = acc & c(0, head(acc, -1)))
```

Then to compute the means for example:

```
sapply(sub.list, with, mean(RT[is.valid]))
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that another `is.valid` column would be useful.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and great suggestions! I learned from each of your posts. I ended up going with something along these lines.

Comment: The `Hmisc` package has a `Lag` convenience function which can replace the `c(0, ...)` construction.

Comment: @krlmlr, `Hmisc::Lag` prepends with `NA` which would be counter-productive here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `mutate` function in the `plyr` package to achieve this task

Let's first recreate the data and set the seeed to make this example reproductible.

```
set.seed(123)
sub1 <- data.frame(acc = round(rnorm(10, mean=.65, sd=.25), 0), 
                   RT = round(rnorm(10, mean=270, sd=30), 0))
sub2 <- data.frame(acc = round(rnorm(10, mean=.65, sd=.25), 0), 
                   RT = round(rnorm(10, mean=270, sd=30), 0))
sub3 <- data.frame(acc = round(rnorm(10, mean=.65, sd=.25), 0), 
                   RT = round(rnorm(10, mean=270, sd=30), 0))

sub_list <- list(sub1, sub2, sub3)
```

Now we can apply the `mutate` function to each dataframe in your list

```
require(plyr)
lapply(sub_list, mutate, acclag = c(NA, head(acc, -1)), 
                    correctRT = ifelse((acc == 0 | acclag == 0), NA, RT))

## [[1]]
##    acc  RT acclag correctRT
## 1    1 307     NA        NA
## 2    1 281      1       281
## 3    1 282      1       282
## 4    1 273      1       273
## 5    1 253      1       253
## 6    1 324      1       324
## 7    1 285      1       285
## 8    0 211      1        NA
## 9    0 291      0        NA
## 10   1 256      0        NA

## [[2]]
##    acc  RT acclag correctRT
## 1    0 283     NA        NA
## 2    1 261      0        NA
## 3    0 297      1        NA
## 4    0 296      0        NA
## 5    0 295      0        NA
## 6    0 291      0        NA
## 7    1 287      0        NA
## 8    1 268      1       268
## 9    0 261      1        NA
## 10   1 259      0        NA

## [[3]]
##    acc  RT acclag correctRT
## 1    0 278     NA        NA
## 2    1 269      0        NA
## 3    0 269      1        NA
## 4    1 311      0        NA
## 5    1 263      1       263
## 6    0 315      1        NA
## 7    1 224      0        NA
## 8    1 288      1       288
## 9    1 274      1       274
## 10   1 276      1       276
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(sub.list,
       function(x) {
         a <- x$acc
         # Choose elements which are true, and previous is also true:
         b <- a & c(0, a[-length(a)])
         x$correctRT <- ifelse(b, x$RT, NA)
         x
       })
```